# Как в боте телеграм обратится к предыдущему сообщению?

Tags: php, telegram-bot

хочу сделать меню с выбором нескольких настроек.
Пишем Старт, Бот предлагает несколько вариантов ответа.
Мы нажали на кнопку, отправилось боту сообщение с текстом, далее бот выдает нам еще одно меню, мы нажимаем кнопку, бот выдает третье  и так по порядку.

в конечном результате что бы бот выдал ответ пользователю

1. Текст первой кнопки
2. Текст второй кнопки
3. Текст третьей кнопки

Хотел вообще записывать сообщения пользователей в txt файлы... По моему мнению это будет тихий ужас. Как можно это реализовать на PHP?

Comment: да элементарно хранить это всё в любой коллекции

Comment: В общем решил проблему, начал сохранять сообщения в mysql, как раз нужные 3. А потом просто обращаюсь к базе и беру оттуда информацию!